# Render a partial with a collection through multiple levels of has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collections, partial-views, has-many-through

I am trying to show a collection of orders that belongs to a sellers products posts

the buyer is the user_id in the order, the seller is the user_id in the product

Quickly:
A user has many products
A product has many postings (to bring products to multiple events)
A post has many orders (other users can order)

Here's my code

```
        class User < ActiveRecord::Base
          # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
          # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
          devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
                 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

          # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
          attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                          :bio, :reason, :barter

                          #:email, :name, :bio, :reason, :barter, :

          has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
          has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
          has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy

            class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
                belongs_to :user
                belongs_to :club
                belongs_to :category
                has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy

            class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
                      belongs_to :product, :include => [:user]
                belongs_to :event
                has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
                accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders

            class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
                belongs_to :user
                belongs_to :post
#schema
  create_table "orders", :force => true do |t|
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.float    "order_price"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "payment_received"
    t.integer  "mark_for_buyer"
    t.string   "comment_for_buyer"
    t.integer  "mark_for_seller"
    t.string   "comment_for_seller"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "orders", ["post_id"], :name => "index_orders_on_post_id"
  add_index "orders", ["user_id"], :name => "index_orders_on_user_id"

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "desc"
    t.text     "ingredients"
    t.float    "deposit"
    t.float    "cost"
    t.string   "units"
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.float    "deadline_hours"
    t.boolean  "presell_option"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "club_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

## orders/index.html.erb

```
        #this one works beautifully 
        <%= render :partial => "order", :collection => @orders.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id), :locals => {:order => @order}  %>
        #this one doesn't work (has_many association resources have been tricky for me)
        <%= render :partial => "order", :collection => @orders.where(:post => {:product  => {:user_id => current_user.id}}) , :locals => {:order => @order}  %>
```

## orders/_order.html.erb

```
  <tr>
    <td><%= order.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= order.post.product.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to order.post.product.title, order.post %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency order.order_price %></td>
    <td><%= order.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= order.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:short) %> </td>
    <td><%= order.payment_received %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', order %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', order, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
```

Now, one collection works great, where the order has a user_id field, it collects the user that made the order and shows all the correct orders.
The other collection doesn't work, and I'm getting this error:

## Error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders#index - No attribute named `user_id` exists for table `product`
```

But there IS a 'user_id' field in the 'product' table.  I am able to call this in cancan to limit management of orders to the user who owns the product that is ordered, and works beautifully

```
can :update, Order, :post => {:product => {:user_id => user.id }}
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the trick is this gem http://rubygems.org/gems/nested_has_many_through which can do something like this:

```
class Author < User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :categories, :through => :posts, :uniq => true
  has_many :similar_posts, :through => :categories, :source => :posts
  has_many :similar_authors, :through => :similar_posts, :source => :author, :uniq => true
  has_many :posts_of_similar_authors, :through => :similar_authors, :source => :posts, :uniq => true
  has_many :commenters, :through => :posts, :uniq => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commenters, :through => :comments, :source => :user, :uniq => true
end
```

This has super-simplified my queries and collections.

This is all the code I ended up needing.  I'm told the gem nested_has_many_through will be standard in Rails 3.1

## User model

```
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_posts, :through => :products, :source => :posts, :uniq => true
  has_many :food_orders, :through => :product_posts, :source => :orders, :uniq => true
```

## OrdersController

```
 @orders_for_my_products = current_user.food_orders.all
```

## Orders index

```
<%= render :partial => "order", :collection => @orders_for_my_products, :locals => {:order => @order}  %>
```

This returns the deep nested data via relationships using minimal code.  I sure hope its efficient, but at least my sanity is spared!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). It explains why what you're doing is causing problems (no separation of concerns = spaghetti code). Also check out [ActiveSupport::Delegate](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/) to see how you can concisely apply the Law of Demeter to your Rails app and avoid lists of boring getters and setters.

A few notes to help you out:

1. Make all your ActiveRecord calls like `where` in your controller. Your view should have arrays (or ActiveSupport::Proxy's) to simply iterate over and display. You should avoid having your view trigger database queries, and you should never keep record-fetching business logic in them.
2. Rather than chaining endlessly on your model associations, define or delegate methods from one model to another. For example, instead of `@comment.post.title`, define and use `@comment.post_title` instead (note the underscore). This avoids requiring your view to have innate knowledge of your database schema and model associations. It simply needs to know that a comment has a post title, however that data is modeled.

If you refactor your code to keep each model focused on a single concern and modeling a single resource, then layer the associations on top of that in a clean, compartmentalized fashion, you will surely obviate the need for someone to solve this single question for you (teach a man to fish…).

Comment: This is great, I'm feeling very close to a breakthrough (with some good habits to boot).  Any hints on forming the query?  I refactored to get @order.post_product_user_id showing up in my index (it works), but when I query Order.where(:post_product_user_id => current_user.id), I get "No attribute named `post_product_user_id` exists for table `orders`".  Nothing really showed up in my research yet, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You still are chaining through models it sounds like. In your controller action you should be handling fetching records with something like `@orders = current_user.orders`. I don't understand why you're even touching the Post or Product models to get to your user when your User and Order models are associated directly.

Comment: I'm doing this to keep the programming DRY.  The user associated with the order is the buyer, and is easily accessible.  The seller is associated with the product, I don't want to repeat the seller id in the order since it is already accessable through the association.  Is this an appropriate use of DRY?

Comment: I don't think DRY is the concept you're applying here, but I do think you should give them appropriate names, e.g. `belongs_to :buyer, :class => 'User'` (which means your foreign key is `buyer_id`). Essentially you need to separate your models from each other as much as possible; they need only know what models they are directly associated with have available. So `order.products.each { |prod| prod.seller_name }` is about as interlinked as you want to get.

Comment: Do you think the https://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through gem will do what I'm attempting?  I was told this is standard in rails 3.1